# Key error trying to run basic ubuntu image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a basic image as described in the Docker tutorial:-

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.9.0, build 76d6bc9

docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

but it is reporting:

```
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: x509: certificate is valid for FG3K6C3A15800002, not index.docker.io
```

I'm behind a corporate firewall, so have set http_proxy and https_proxy env variables appropriately. The server itself is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I've read various posts about clock settings etc, but these seem OK.

Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: Give this a a try: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you state having set your proxy variable, make sure to try this *full* set of proxy variables n your `/etc/default/docker`:

```
export "HTTP_PROXY=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy.company.com>:<port>"
export "HTTPS_PROXY=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy.company.com>:<port>"
export "http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy.company.com>:<port>"
export "https_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<proxy.company.com>:<port>"
export "NO_PROXY=.company.com,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
export "no_proxy=.company.com,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1"
```

If that doesn't solve the issue, upgrade docker to the latest 1.10.1.

Note: [docker machine issue 531](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/531#issuecomment-245919968) mentions `docker-machine provision` as a workaround.

---

Update [2021 on issue 531](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/531#issuecomment-806376767)

> I had the same exact issue just now and apparently it was fixed by resetting docker to factory settings and enabling the Kubernetes cluster again.
>
> EDIT: I managed to reproduce the fix on a second machine. The exact steps in my case were:
>
> - start Docker Desktop
> - update to 3.2.1 -> immediately after this another updated was available to 3.2.2
> - update to 3.2.2
> - enable Kubernetes cluster -> wait until the error appears
> - right click on Docker in the System Tray -> choose Troubleshoot
> - click Reset to factory defaults -> wait until the reset is finished
> - right click on Docker in the System Tray -> choose Quit Docker Desktop
> - open Docker Desktop again
> - select only Enable Kubernetes